# "Cancel" Modal with Angular from a List is not doing the undo on the model

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of employees, I am using a table with a repeater to show the list:

```
...
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage]" ng-click="ItemClick(item)">
      <td>{{item.EmployeeID}}</td>
      <td>{{item.EmployeeName}}</td>
      <td>{{item.StartDate}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

I am opening my modal when item is clicked, and I am making a copy of the original object:

```
$scope.ItemClick = function (item) {

    item.Original = angular.copy(item);

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
          resolve: {
               selectedItem: function () {
               return item;
               }
          }
    });

};
```

And I have my template for the modal form:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Employee Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem.EmployeeName" />
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
     <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
   </td>
<tr>
</table>
```

And I have my two methods for save and cancel:

```
$scope.cancel = function () {

  $scope.selectedItem = angular.copy($scope.selectedItem.Original)

  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

$scope.save = function () {

     // Some code here to call server and save the data

     $modalInstance.close($scope.selectedItem);
};
```

Ok, Now the problem I am having is, when Saving is successful everything is fine, the list show the right new information, but when "Cancel" the form, after some modifications, the list is still showing the modified information even if I press cancel, it should return to the original state, the same happen if i have an error on the server side. Any ideas?

Comment: You resolve selectedItem should do ` return item.Original`

Comment: You should just do `return  angular.copy(item)` in the resolve and get the data from `modalInstance .result.then(function(updateditem){assign it to the scope})`

Comment: thanks Chander and PSL, the first part works, now I don't have the problem with the cancel, the saving is working on the server, but when closing the modal the list still show the original info, @PSL where should i place the code the code for modalInstance.result

Comment: @ChrisOnDaRocks Inside the itemclick. it is modal result resolve callback. it will give you what you pass in using `$modalInstance.close($scope.selectedItem);` from your modal. And you just need to clone the item in the resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, i tried working with a copy of the original item, and then when save to make the changes on the model, but i had no luck, then I change the approach to the original one which is making a copy of the original value, and passing the current item, then if cancel I rollback the item from model and the list, I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but it is working, i just add the next code inside the ItemClick after the calling the modal Open:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (updatedItem) {
    // Successful no need to do anything
    }, function (result) {
          // Dismiss
          item = item.Original;
          angular.forEach($scope.pagedItems[$scope.currentPage], function (value, key) {
            if (value.EmployeeID == item.EmployeeID) {
                   $scope.pagedItems[$scope.currentPage][key] = angular.copy(item)
                   return;
            }
     });
  });
```